# asp.net mvc view data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I create a class to hold view data for two different types from my model.

```
class FooBarViewData
{
    public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

I typed my view to a FooBarViewData but it fails to find the type.

```
<%@ Page Title="" 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<FooBarViewData>" %>
```

How can I get this to work.  Also once it does work, how do I access Foo and Bar, by a key on the ViewData collection or another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try specifying the full namespace? Like, err, MyProject.ViewDTO.FooBarViewData ?

When it DOES register, you can access your typed viewdata via the Model property on the view. This should work:

```
<% foreach(Foo foo in Model.Foos) { %>
  <%= Foo.ToString() %>
<% } %>
```